# Python Countdown but in Year, Month, Week, Days, Hours, Minutes, Sec

Tags: python, datetime, countdown

I would like to have my lifetime displayed in the form of a countdown. Unfortunately, Python datetime only allows days. And couldn't program a conversion

this is what i tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import timedelta


while True:
        lebenszeit = datetime.datetime(2085,7,6) - datetime.datetime.now()
        jahr     = str(int((lebenszeit.days)/365.25))
        monate   = str('%0.2d' %(int((((lebenszeit.days)*365)-int((lebenszeit.days)/365))*12)))
        tage     = str('%0.2d' %(int(((((lebenszeit.days)/365)-int((lebenszeit.days)/365))*12)-((((lebenszeit.days)/365)-int((lebenszeit.days)/365))*12)*30)))
        print(jahr+"."+monate+"."+tag)

        i = i+1
```

as you can see very complicated...

I would like to have a countdown that should look like this ( Year, Month, Week, Days, Hours, Minutes, Secounds):

```
68.02.04.29.07.40.44
```

Comment: A python timedelta only contains days because a year and month isn't a consistent number of days.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it. Note that "months" is approximate, assuming 30 days per month. Using only "weeks" would be more accurate.

```
import time
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

lebenszeit  = datetime.datetime(2085,7,6) - datetime.datetime.now()
alldays = lebenszeit.days

jahr     = int((alldays)/365.25)
alldays -= int(jahr * 365.25)
months   = int((alldays)/30.0)
alldays -= months * 30
weeks    = int((alldays)/7.0)
alldays -= weeks * 7
days     = alldays

print(f"{jahr}.{months:02d}.{weeks:02d}.{days:02d}")
```

Comment: yes darn. now i see it. Weeks have a crooked conversion, 52.1429 makes a year.... But is better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot be run. But here are some tips:

```py
import datetime


life = datetime.datetime(2085,7,6)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
diff = life - now
# use in a loop, that's a lot to print
for i in range(int(diff.total_seconds()) + 1):
    one_sec_step = life - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i)
    # one_sec_step = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=i)
    print(one_sec_step.strftime("%y.%m.%W.%d.%H.%M.%S"))
```

How to get year, month, day, hour, minute, second:

```py
# datetime.datetime object has no attribute week

life = datetime.datetime(2085,7,6)
print(life.year, life.month, life.day, life.hour, life.minute, life.second)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks user 8349697,
but this script run on a real clock. Therefore, the "for-loop" is always linked to the computing speed of the CPU. I would like to avoid this.

I was so free to break the script of Kevins down to the seconds.

```
import datetime

lebenszeit  = datetime.datetime(2085,6,7,0,0,0) - datetime.datetime.now()
alldays = lebenszeit.days
allsec  = lebenszeit.seconds

jahr     = int((alldays)/365.25)
alldays -= int(jahr * 365.25)
months   = int((alldays)/30.0)
alldays -= months * 30
weeks    = int((alldays)/7.0)
alldays -= weeks * 7
days     = alldays365.25

hours    = int((allsec)/60/60)
allsec  -= int(hours * 60*60)
minutes  = int((allsec)/60)
allsec  -= int(minutes *60)
secounds = int(allsec)

print(f"{jahr}.{months:02d}.{weeks:02d}.{days:02d}.{hours:02d}.{minutes}.{secounds}")
```